# How to convert text date to timestamp?

Tags: perl

How to convert date in text format:

```
23.10.2011  11:35:00
```

to timestamp ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) , you can do:

```
use Time::Local;

my $date = '23.10.2011  11:35:00';
my ($mday,$mon,$year,$hour,$min,$sec) = split(/[\s.:]+/, $date);
my $time = timelocal($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon-1,$year);
print $time,"\n",scalar localtime $time;
```

**Output:**

```
1319362500
Sun Oct 23 11:35:00 2011
```

Comment: `timelocal()` is [discouraged](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time::Local#timelocal()-and-timegm()). Not sure about `timelocal_posix()` vs `timelocal_modern()`.

Answer (score 18):

I'd look into [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime) and the [parsing modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=DateTime::Format&mode=all).

```
perl -MDateTime::Format::Strptime -le'$strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => "%d.%m.%Y  %T", time_zone => "local"); $dt = $strp->parse_datetime("23.10.2011  11:35:00"); print $dt->epoch'
1319384100 at -e line 1.
```

Same as above, but not a one-liner:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern => '%d.%m.%Y  %T',
   time_zone => 'local',
);
my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime('23.10.2011  11:35:00');
print $dt->epoch;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Date::Parse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse) in Perl is very elegante option too.
Maybe someone will found this useful:

```
$gmtdate = 'Jul 12 00:12:26 2021 GMT';
my $timestamp = str2time($gmtdate);
```

Comment: It might be a good option (I don't know, haven't used it), but it e.g. won't parse `%d.%m.%Y %H:%M`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the [`Time::Piece`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time::Piece) answer was deleted. Maybe because it (`Time::Piece`) has its [quirks](https://github.com/Dual-Life/Time-Piece/issues/52#issuecomment-1246310525). But it's more powerful than `Date::Parse` (although less powerful than `DateTime`, but [some say](https://www.perl.com/article/59/2014/1/10/Solve-almost-any-datetime-need-with-Time--Piece/) it covers most of the needs), it's a core module, and you don't have to parse the string as with `Time::Local`. But datetime math is apparently not DST-safe.

Long story short:

```
use Time::Piece;
my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime("23.10.2011  11:35:00", 
                               "%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M:%S");
# or this way (if the timestamp is in the local time zone):
# $tp = localtime->strptime("23.10.2011  11:35:00",
#                           "%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M:%S");
print $tp;
```

More on creating `Time::Piece` objects [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/4aa50308bab6bb41c5c8dd8ebdc7defb).