# convert timestamp to d-m-Y format data perl

Tags: perl, time, date-format

i have the following timestamp:

```
 2015-06-25 11:27:38.152933+03
```

I want to convert it to something like this:

```
 25-06-2015
```

How can i do this in perl? Thanks.

Comment: The first format is considerably more useful, generally, because it's following the ISO 8601 standard. (And is thus numerically sortable and not ambiguous US vs. almost everywhere else).

Comment: i was asked to convert the specific timestamp to this format...it was not my decision...is there a reason for downvoting me?

Comment: I didn't. But it's not unusual when you ask for a solution to a problem without showing any attempt yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple regular expression to grab the year, month and date, and then build up your date string using [the `sprintf` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

```
my $timestamp = '2015-06-25 11:27:38.152933+03';
$timestamp =~ m/^(....)-(..)-(..)\s/;
my $date = sprintf '%02d-%02d-%4d', $3, $2, $1;
```

This will output:

```
25-06-2015
```

Since you don't care about the time and time zone, there is no need for a full-blown parser. Rolling your own very simple one suffices.

Comment: how can i save the output to a variable?

Comment: @tsiro I updated the answer. You need to use `sprintf` instead of `printf`.

Comment: Safer: `my $date = $timestamp =~ m/^(....)-(..)-(..)\s/ ? sprintf '%02d-%02d-%4d', $3, $2, $1 : undef;`

Answer (score 0):

Even if this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726514/how-to-convert-text-date-to-timestamp) is not exactly about your problem you will find a concise way to parse your timestamp string into its components (month, year, etc.) and then it should be pretty simple to put them back together as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered, but for future reference:

```
use Time::Moment;
say Time::Moment->from_string('2015-06-25 11:27:38.152933+03', lenient => 1)
                ->strftime("%d-%m-%Y");
```

Output:

```
25-06-2015
```

Now you probably think the regex solution provided by @simbabque is faster? Time for a simple benchmark:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark    qw[];
use Time::Moment qw[];

my $timestamp = '2015-06-25 11:27:38.152933+03';

Benchmark::cmpthese( -10, {
    'regex' => sub {
        $timestamp =~ m/^(....)-(..)-(..)/;
        my $string = sprintf '%02d-%02d-%4d', $3, $2, $1;
    },
    'Time::Moment' => sub {
        my $string = Time::Moment->from_string($timestamp, lenient => 1)
                                 ->strftime("%d-%m-%Y");
    },
});
```

Result:

```
                  Rate        regex Time::Moment
regex        1256682/s           --          -8%
Time::Moment 1368953/s           9%           --
```

[Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment) is faster even though it's a strict parser which validates the  date/time components of the given timestamp string. In the interest of full disclosure, I am the author of Time::Moment.