# Perl convert YYYYMMDD to 16digit epoch time

Tags: perl

Is there a perl function that converts YYYYMMDD to a 16digit epoch time?

I'm currently calling the date command:

```
date -d 20160219 +%s%6N
```

for the conversion but my script takes a long time to go through the millions of dates in my data set.

By "16digit epoch time", I mean a 16-digit decimal integer representing microseconds since the epoch. For example, `2016-02-19 00:00:00 UTC` is 1455840000 seconds after the epoch, so the result I want is `"1455840000000000"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert text date to timestamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726514/how-to-convert-text-date-to-timestamp)

Comment: do you know how I can make it 16 digits? and do you know if it has better performance than calling the bash date function?

Comment: learn the concepts, and then you can convert any kind of date/time string to a timestamp, instead of flailing around for an extremely specific solution, and then getting stuck again when that format changes ever so slightly.

Comment: To convert 10 digits to 16 digits, add "000000" to the end.

Comment: You didn't clearly explain what you meant by "16digit epoch time", and most readers probably don't know what `%6N` means. I've updated your question (which, @MarcB, is not a duplicate). So all your timestamps specify only the day. Do you want midnight of that day? In the current local time zone?

Comment: Incidentally, that representation happens to be 16 digits only from Sun 2001-09-09 01:46:40 UTC to Sat 2286-11-20 17:46:39 UTC. The upper bound probably isn't an issue, but if you have dates before 2001, decide whether you want to pad them with leading 0s.

Comment: so basically a javascript-style millisecond timestamp? then it still is a dupe. convert to a conventional "seconds since the epoch" timestamp, then multiply by 1000.

Comment: That's correct. The dates are all midnight. I don't have any dates before 2001.

Comment: @MarcB Microseconds, not milliseconds (10^6)

Comment: either way, simple math, especially since the source is a date value only anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment). In the interest of full disclosure, I am the author of Time::Moment.

```
use v5.10;
use Time::Moment;

say Time::Moment->from_string('20160219' . 'T00Z')
                ->strftime('%s%6N');
```

Output:

```
1455840000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) can do all the things you want. After that just right pad `0`'s to epoch, so that it becomes 16 digits.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $t = Time::Piece -> strptime("20160219",
                                       "%Y%m%d");
my $epoch = $t -> epoch;

# make $epoch 16 digits
$epoch .= "0" x (16 - length($epoch));

print "$epoch\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Time::Local core module:

```
use Time::Local 'timelocal';

$date = "20160218";
($year, $month, $day) = unpack "A4A2A2", $date;

$time = timelocal(0, 0, 0, $day, $month-1, $year);
$time .= '000000';
```

Answer (score -3):

Wow, I just actually wrote a script to take the timestamp where it takes a timestamp where it's in seconds since epoch and convert it to human readable format. Not what you asked, but perhaps you can reverse what I wrote.

```
my $ts = $ARGV[0]; #2012-09-04-20:24:19.870 1030825460
my $newTs = toTimeString($ts);
print "\n".$newTs."\n";


## Convert from time since epoch in seconds to string YYYY-MM-DD-HH:mm:ss.sss
sub toTimeString{   
    my $ts=shift;
    $ts += 432000; # Add 5 days to make computation easy.
    my $sec = $ts-int($ts/60)*60; # Seconds
    $ts = int($ts/60); # Convert to minutes
    my $min = $ts%60; # minutes
    $ts = int($ts/60); # Convert to hours.
    my $hr = $ts%24; # hours;
    $ts = int($ts/24); # Convert to days.
    my $yr;
    my $mo;
    my $day;
    my $days =  [   [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31],
                    [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
                ];
    our $cumDays =  [   [0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334],
                    [0,31,60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335]
                ];
    if($ts<366){$yr=1980;}
    else{
        $yr = 1981 + int(($ts-366)/1461)*4;
        $ts = $ts - 366 - int(($ts-366)/1461)*1461;
        if($ts < 1095){$yr += int($ts/365); $ts = $ts - int($ts/365)*365;}
        else{$yr = $yr+3; $ts=$ts-1095;}
    }
    my $leap=0;
    my $i;
    if($yr%4 == 0){$leap=1;}
    for($i=0;$i<12;$i++){
        if($ts > $cumDays->[$leap]->[$i]){
            $mo=$i+1;
        }
    }
    $day=$ts-$cumDays->[$leap]->[$mo-1]+1;
    my $ret;
    $ret = sprintf("%04d",$yr)."-".sprintf("%02d",$mo)."-".sprintf("%02d",$day)."-";
    $ret = $ret.sprintf("%02d",$hr).":".sprintf("%02d",$min).":".sprintf("%02d",int($sec));
    $ret = $ret."\.".sprintf("%03d",int($sec*1000)%1000);
    return ($ret)
}
```

Comment: I think my jaw just hit the floor.

Comment: well, it's not what the OP asked, but I often need to convert seconds from epoch to readable timestamps from our logs when I print it to .csv files and I wrote this to help me.

Comment: Not just that, but there are well-tested libraries available that can do the same thing in 2 lines.

Comment: I can tell you put a lot of effort into this, but did you test it? It returns `2026-02-23-03:00:10.000` for an input of now and `1980-01-06-00:00:00.000` for an input of zero (should be 1970-01-01). This is why @MattJacob recommended you use an existing module.