# How do I copy the latest from ftp in a perl script

Tags: file, datetime, perl, timestamp

I have a perl script which copies one file from a directory on an ftp server. The filename has the form FPZB01_00000118.txt. The number before .txt is incremented by 1 every day. There should be only one file on the remote server each day. If there are more than 1 files, the script will copies all the files, which is not desired. I am trying to add code to copy only today's file, but am stuck.
The code is below, leaving out use::strict, ... and other definitions.

```
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new( $host, Timeout => 360, Passive => 1, Debug=>1 ) or die "Error connecting to $host: $!\n";
$ftp->binary();
$ftp->login($User,$Pass) or die "Cannot login to $User\n";
$ftp->cwd($remote_dir) or die "Could not change remote working directory to  $remote_dir\n";
my @remote_files = $ftp->ls($glob);
```

Added code

```
my @file2copy = grep /^FPZB01/, $ftp->ls();
foreach my $fl (@file2copy){
 my $mdtime = $ftp->mdtm($fl);
 print $f "modtime $mdtime\n";
 exit;
}
```

End Added code

```
foreach my $file (@remote_files) {

 # Transfer file
 print "Getting $file\n" if $debug;
 eval {$ftp->get($file, "$local_dir/$file") or print("Can't send file $file\n")};
 if ($@ =~ /Timeout/){
  print "Got a timeout Issue: $@";
 }     
}

#   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
print "copying ends\n";
 exit 0;
```

I have tried to print the modification `print $f "modtime $mdtime\n"`;
This is what I get:

```
modtime 1697627482.
```

No idea what this means.
Assistance will appreciated on how to use `$ftp->mdtm($fl)`

Comment: *"No idea what this means. "* - looks like [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), i.e. number of seconds since 70/01/01. But in general - higher numbers mean more current, so you can easily figure out what the newest file is by comparing.

Comment: Thanks @ Ullrich, it is indeed seconds since 01/01/1970. I will try to work out from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort the list of files and transfer the last one in the array.

```
# Use grep to ignore any files with the wrong name
my @remote_files = grep { /^FPZB/ } sort $ftp->ls($glob);

my $file_to_transfer = $remote_files[-1];
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave Corss, I will try your solution also. Incidentally, it is the time of modification that is important here not the name.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba: But you said the digits at the end of the name are incremented each day. So you can ignore the modification time and just use the filename.

Comment: Once again thanks @Dave, this works but apparently $remote_files[-1]; gives the oldest file, which is ok because to get the latest I can just get $remote_files[0];. I appreciate. As for the other code below, I have a problem with handling the word epoch on my system.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba: if the number at the end of the filename increments daily and you're running my code as I wrote it, then `$remote_files[-1]` must be the latest file. If that's not the case, then there's something else going on that you're not telling us about.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I added to make it work
I got time 12 hours ago

```
my $TodayDate = strftime "%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M:%S", localtime(time - 12*60*60);
```

After login, calculate the epoch time of my date 12 hours ago

```
my ($mday,$mon,$year,$hour,$min,$sec) = split(/[\s.:]+/, $TodayDate);
my $time = timelocal($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon-1,$year);
```

I then loop through the files and look only for files newer than 12 hours ago

```
    my @file2copy = grep /^FPZB01/, $ftp->ls();
foreach my $fl (@file2copy){
 my $mdtime = $ftp->mdtm($fl);
 if($mdtime > $time){
  #Transfer file
```

The rest of the code in unchanged, transferring the file. This is not elegant but it does what I wanted.
Added in preamble

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
use POSIX qw{strftime};
use Time::Local
use Time::Piece;
use Net::FTP;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
```

Thanks to Ullrich, and to Toto at [How to convert text date to timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726514/how-to-convert-text-date-to-timestamp)

Comment: But you say "The number before .txt is incremented by 1 every day". So the whole thing about modification time is pointless. You can just sort the filenames and select the one with the highest number.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly the criterion for file selection is, as the question seems to differ slightly from some OP's comments and perhaps from OP's own answer.  Here are some options.

---

Being newer than 12 hours is used as a criterion in OP's answer.  That can be used with

```
my @file2copy = grep { -M < 0.5 } $ftp->ls();
```

since `-M` [filetest (-X)](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X) gives

> -M  Script start time minus file modification time, in days.

That can also be sorted (see below) to get the latest, if needed.

---

In an OP's comment the modification time is mentioned, what can be used for example by

```
use Sort::Key qw(rukeysort);  # Reverse (descending) sort as Unsigned integers

my @files_latest_mtime = rukeysort { (stat $_)[9] } $ftp->ls();
```

The [Sort::Key](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key) library functions are very convenient when more complex sorting criteria are needed as one can use a comparison criterion directly (and internally it uses the Schwartzian transform for efficiency).  I use [stat](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat) to get modification time (in seconds since epoch); then larger times are for newer files so we need the "reverse" sort (descending).

---

One can also use a date-time library and build objects out of modtime from timestamps, what can then be used any way you please.  With [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime)

```
use DateTime;
use Sort::Key qw(rukeysort);

# Build an array with [filename,dt] arrayrefs, newest files first
my @files_dt_latest =
    # grep if needed
    rukeysort { $_->[1]->epoch }
    map { [$_, DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => (stat $_)[9])] } 
        $ftp->ls();

say "$_->[0] => $_->[1]" for @files_dt_latest;
```

where `epoch` returns file's age in seconds since epoch, convenient for sorting.  Or use a hash

```
my %file_dt = 
    map { $_ => DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => (stat $_)[9])] } 
        $ftp->ls();
```

and this can be manipulated as needed

```
foreach my $file (rukeysort { $file_dt{$_}->epoch } keys %file_dt) { 
    say "$file => $file_dt{$file}"  # newest first
}
```

---

Or use a library, here `DateTime`, to get today's date, say in seconds since epoch for easy comparison with files' timestamps.  To get only today's files:

```
use DateTime;
use Sort::Key qw(rukeysort);

# "today" returns today's date at 00:00:00, in UTC by default
my $today_epoch = DateTime->today(time_zone => 'local')->epoch;

my @files_today_latest_by_mtime = 
    rukeysort { (stat $_)[9] } 
    grep { (stat $_)[9] > $today_epoch } 
        $ftp->ls();
```

This cna perhaps be optimized for performance (or style?) as `stat` is used repeatedly but I doubt that one could tell the difference. And a "better" version would be more complex.

Comment: This is very interesting. I will try it and give feedback